# If someone looks at a boy because of me,do I get sins?

Tags: halal-haram

I hung up a funny picture from pinterest that had a boy in the background with funny text,but then I thought about the fact that girls shouldn’t look at boys and I didn’t want to get a sin for every single girl that looks at the picture so I took it off. But I don’t know if it’s wrong or not,and if I can put it or not because I really want to,and I don’t know so can someone help?